# How to calibrate dual (stereo) camera and obtain data?

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My knowledge of ROS/Linux is limited, so I'm hoping someone could kindly help me.

I am using Virtual Box running Linux 14.04, and ROS Indigo.

I am trying to use a dual camera setup in order to obtain stereo vision via ROS.
The cameras are on this USB module that I can access, and when I try to open it in Windows, I see the cameras as two different devices. I can also see them as two video devices on my VM.

> ls /dev/video*

> /dev/video0    /dev/video1

However, both cheese nor GTK UVC video viewer was unable to open the device.
Cheese says "There was an error playing video from the webcam" even though I can see the device being selected in its Preferences.
GTK UVC just captures blackness.

I also tried to use cv_camera but that did not give me a launch file to use.
So I tried libuvc_camera but that also didn't give me a launch file.

I basically did these and not sure how to go from there, without a launch file:

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-cv-camera

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-libuvc-camera

I don't know how to get them to work. I then tried to do the same with the usb_camera package, which has a launch file:

> roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch

But when I used the launch, I get these errors:

> setting /run_id to e42f368a-4a2b-11e6-a2c1-08002755c1aa

> process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11222]

> started core service [/rosout]

> process[usb_cam-2]: started with pid [11236]

> process[image_view-3]: started with pid [11240]

> [ INFO] [1468546306.052415844]: Using transport "raw"

> [ INFO] [1468546306.480381780]: using default calibration URL

> [ INFO] [1468546306.480561586]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/max/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml

> [ INFO] [1468546306.480649985]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/max/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]

> [ WARN] [1468546306.480709246]: Camera calibration file /home/max/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.

> [ INFO] [1468546306.480765315]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video0) at 640x480 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS

> [ERROR] [1468546306.742666755]: VIDIOC_STREAMON error 5, Input/output error

> [usb_cam-2] process has died [pid 11236, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/home/max/.ros/log/e42f368a-4a2b-11e6-a2c1-08002755c1aa/usb_cam-2.log].
> log file: /home/max/.ros/log/e42f368a-4a2b-11e6-a2c1-08002755c1aa/usb_cam-2*.log

Basically 1) I don't know if my webcam is actually connected and 2) I don't know how to use the packages that might help me extract the camera data (let alone stereo data). I know I need to do camera calibration at some point, but I thought libuvc_camera is the best option for that.

I'm very stuck, so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239566/how-to-calibrate-dual-(stereo)-camera-and-obtain-data?/) by [QCBKoala](https://answers.ros.org/users/27491/qcbkoala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm doing the same thing as yours.
I have successfully use [ucv_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera) as camera driver with a launch file below:

mono.launch (use to open one camera)

```
<launch>
    <group ns="camera">
        <node pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_camera_node" name="mycam">
            <!-- Parameters used to find the camera -->
            <param name="device" value="/dev/video0"/>
        </node>
     </group>
</launch>
```

stereo.laumch (open two camera)

```
<launch>
      <group ns="stereo">
           <node pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_stereo_node" name="mycam">
           <!-- Parameters used to find the camera -->
           <param name="left/device" value="/dev/video0"/>
           <param name="right/device" value="/dev/video1"/>
           <param name="width" value="640" />
           <param name="height" value="480" />
           </node>
      </group>
</launch>
```

You can set other parameter as well.

And use [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) to check if driver works.

Hope this hlep you.

---

Originally posted by [ponsheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/27568/ponsheng/) with karma: 106 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [QCBKoala](https://answers.ros.org/users/27491/qcbkoala/) on 2016-08-02**:
It seems to have worked, with some modifications and in combination with another package.
Thanks :)

And I spent all day today trying to extract depth data using the stereo images - with little success.
If this is similar to what you're doing, do you think we can share notes?
Thanks!